# Having strange date range error that only applies to certain date ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Okay, so this is a little hard to explain, basically the code below is comparing a ship date column vs 3 other date columns and then calculating an on time % for each.  I'll explain the exact issue below the code:

```
SELECT
CAST(o.OrderNo AS INT) AS [OrderNo],
o.CustCode,
CASE
    WHEN d2.[Shipment Total] IS NULL THEN o.OrderTotal
    ELSE d2.[Shipment Total]
    END AS [OrderTotal],
CAST(SUBSTRING(o.NotesToCust, CHARINDEX('ISD',o.NotesToCust)+4, 8) AS DATE) AS [ISD],
CAST(o.User_Date1 AS DATE) AS [3 Week Ack Date],
CAST(o.User_Date2 AS DATE) AS [1 Week Ack Date],
CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) AS [Ship Date],
CASE
    WHEN CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%partial%' THEN 'Partial Shipment'
    WHEN CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%complete%' THEN 'Shipped Complete'
    END AS [Shipment Notes],
CAST(CASE
    WHEN o.User_Number3 <> '0'
    THEN o.User_Number3
    ELSE NULL
    END AS INT) AS [Late Reason Code(s)],
(CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) <= CAST(SUBSTRING(o.NotesToCust, CHARINDEX('ISD',o.NotesToCust)+4, 8) AS DATE)
    AND CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) NOT LIKE '%partial%'
    AND (CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IS NULL
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 0
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 3
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 4
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 5
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 6
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 7
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 8
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 9)
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(d.ShipDate)) AS FLOAT))/
        NULLIF((CAST(SUM(CASE
            WHEN CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) NOT LIKE '%partial%'
            AND (CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IS NULL
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 0
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 3
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 4
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 5
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 6
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 7
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 8
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 9)
            AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
            AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(d.ShipDate)) AS FLOAT)),0) AS [ISD On-Time %],
(CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) <= CAST(o.User_Date1 AS DATE)
    AND CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) NOT LIKE '%partial%'
    AND (CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IS NULL
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 0
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 3
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 4
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 5
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 6
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 7
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 8
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 9)
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(d.ShipDate)) AS FLOAT))/
        NULLIF((CAST(SUM(CASE
            WHEN CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) NOT LIKE '%partial%'
            AND (CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IS NULL
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 0
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 3
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 4
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 5
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 6
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 7
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 8
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 9)
            AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
            AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(d.ShipDate)) AS FLOAT)),0) AS [3 Week On-Time %],
(CAST(SUM(CASE
    WHEN CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) <= CAST(o.User_Date2 AS DATE)
    AND CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) NOT LIKE '%partial%'
    AND (CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IS NULL
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 0
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 3
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 4
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 5
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 6
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 7
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 8
    OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 9)
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(d.ShipDate)) AS FLOAT))/
        NULLIF((CAST(SUM(CASE
            WHEN CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX)) NOT LIKE '%partial%'
            AND (CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IS NULL
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 0
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 3
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 4
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 5
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 6
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 7
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 8
            OR CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) = 9)
            AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
            AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(d.ShipDate)) AS FLOAT)),0) AS [1 Week On-Time %]
FROM Orders o 
JOIN OrderDet od ON o.OrderNo = od.OrderNo
JOIN TimeTicketDet t ON od.JobNo = t.JobNo
LEFT JOIN DelTicket d ON o.OrderNo = d.OrderNo AND d.Notes2Cust NOT LIKE '%rework%'
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        od1.OrderNo AS [OrderNo],
        d1.ShipDate AS [ShipDate],
        d1.DelTicketNo AS [DelTicketNo],
        SUM(od1.UnitPrice*od1.QtyOrdered) AS [Shipment Total]
    FROM OrderDet od1
        JOIN DelTicketDet dt1 ON od1.JobNo = dt1.JobNo
        JOIN DelTicket d1 ON dt1.DelTicketNo = d1.DelTicketNo
    GROUP BY od1.OrderNo, d1.ShipDate, d1.DelTicketNo
    ) AS [d2] ON d.OrderNo = d2.OrderNo AND d.ShipDate = d2.ShipDate
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), o.User_Memo1) IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTRING(o.User_Memo1, 1, 3) = 'Cut'
    AND CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180331'
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE '%Euroline%'
    AND o.CustCode NOT LIKE 'Savi B%'
GROUP BY 
o.OrderNo, o.CustCode, d2.[Shipment Total], o.OrderTotal, CAST(SUBSTRING(o.NotesToCust, CHARINDEX('ISD',o.NotesToCust)+4, 8) AS DATE), CAST(o.User_Date1 AS DATE), CAST(o.User_Date2 AS DATE),
CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE), d.ShipDate, o.User_Number3, CAST(d.Notes2Cust AS VARCHAR(MAX))
ORDER BY CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) DESC
```

Okay, so this query returns the following error:
"Conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string"

So okay, I then tried changing this line:

```
AND CAST(d.ShipDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180331'
```

To be in between 20180101 and 20180228 and it works!!  Okay so then I figured that the conversion issue is with something that I shipped between March 1-31.  So then I changed that same line to say in between 20180301 and 20180331, which should not work, however, it does, and this is what is causing me a headache. Essentially, if I were to union the same code with one block saying from 20180101 to 20180228 and the second block to capture the March records, it would work just fine.  However, if I go between Jan 1 and Mar 31, it doesn't work.  What the heck??

I just checked every field that is being converted and there shouldn't be any errors, everything that I am converting to a date should 100% work.  I'm really at a loss at how to proceed here.  Union is not really an option, because I'd need like 25 unions to capture all the data I need over the span of a couple years. Besides, it just doesn't make sense to have to use that as a workaround when the code should execute just fine

Comment: What is the datatype of the `ShipDate` column in the table?

Comment: I assume the ShipDate column of table DelTicket has an invalid date may be 20180229 which is the reason for your error.

Comment: @TabAlleman ShipDate is Date/Time type

Comment: @Dheerendra There is no 2/29 date.  Also, say I go from April 1 to June 30, that won't work, but if I query those months individually (Apr/May/June), they each work.  I can't make sense of it

Comment: What happens if you comment out all the places where you've got `CAST(SUBSTRING(o.NotesToCust, CHARINDEX('ISD',o.NotesToCust)+4, 8) AS DATE)`?

Comment: AS [d2] ON d.OrderNo = d2.OrderNo AND d.ShipDate = d2.ShipDate Shouldn't be the shipdates casted while joining? are you joining along with time stamps?

Comment: @TabAlleman If I remove the group by and the [ISD On-Time %] column, the query executes for any date range, although without the GROUP BY, the query calculates incorrectly for the last two columns.  Strangely, the ISD column executes as well under this scenario so CAST(SUBSTRING(o.NotesToCust, CHARINDEX('ISD',o.NotesToCust)+4, 8) AS DATE) is not the definite source of the error

Comment: You can simplify some conditions by using IN: `CAST(o.User_Number3 AS INT) IN (0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` or  `o.User_Number3 IN ('0', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')`. But all these casts tell me that the type of many columns is just wrong. Why store dates and numbers in varchar columns?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Believe me, I tried simplifying that section, I just need WHERE <> 1 and 2, but for some reason the math wasn't coming out right.  In other queries, I've noticed the User_Number3 field is problematic.  As far as casting to dates, it's mostly for consistency I suppose.  The only cast I really need to make is the one on the NotesToCust column, and that's because we ran out of date fields.  I've solved the issue by simply changing all the CASTS to TRY_CAST.  There are no nulls or conversion errors on my 4 date columns when I use TRY_CAST, so no idea why CAST alone crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't enough information to give you a definitive answer, but here is how you can find it.

The error occurs because you try to cast a string to a date and the string isn't a valid date.  The snippet `CAST(SUBSTRING(o.NotesToCust, CHARINDEX('ISD',o.NotesToCust)+4, 8) AS DATE)` is obviously casting a string to a date, but I don't know where else in your query it might be happening, because I don't know which of your columns are strings, and which are date/datetime.

But what you can do is, everywhere in your query where you cast a varchar to a date, you can change the cast to TRY_CAST(), and look for the rows where TRY_CAST() resulted in a NULL being returned.   Then you'll find the rows that are causing the error.

Comment: OMG, I just changed all the CASTS to TRY_CAST and the query works perfectly now for all dates after '20180101'.  All 4 of my date columns are filled in correctly, no nulls.  The CAST only version simply does not work and I don't know why.  Whatever TRY_CAST does differently is the answer.  All my records for the last 13 months are there.  I also just verified the math on my 3 On-Time % columns and they are spot on.  The only change I had to make was to add the YEAR to the PARTITION clause, since my 2018 and 2019 Januarys were overlapping.  AWESOME!!!